# Uncaught ReferenceError: <variable name> is not defined

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I am new to d3, just tried some sample code but getting reference error.

Create an HTML file index2.html at any proper location on disk

```
<html>
<head>
<title>D3</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> barChart</h1>
<div id = "chart"></div>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

create index2.js file in the same location where the previous HTML file was created

```
function barChart() {
    var that = {};

    that.render = function() {
        var myData = [10,20,30,40,50,60];
        var height = 500;
            var width = 500;
          var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
            .style('padding', '5 15px')
            .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
            .style('border-radius', '5px')
            .style('opacity', '0')
      };

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(myData)])
            .range([0, height]);

        var xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(d3.range(0, myData.length))
            .rangeBands([0, width])
        var myChart = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
                .selectAll('rect')
                    .data(myData)
                    .enter().append('rect')
                        .style('fill', function(d, i){
                            return colors(i);
                        })
                        .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
                        .attr('height', 0)
                        .attr('x', function(d, i){
                            return xScale(i);
                        })
                        .attr('y', height)
                .on('mouseover', function(d){
                    tooltip.transition()
                        .style('opacity', 1)

                    tooltip.html(d)
                        .style('left', (d3.event.pageX)+'px')
                        .style('top', (d3.event.pageY+'px'))
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5)

                })
                .on('mouseout', function(d){
                    tooltip.transition()
                        .style('opacity', 0)
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
                })

        return that;
}

var c=barChart();
c.render();
```

Now Open index2.html in browser. Open javascirpt debug using ctrl+shift+j , we get error as below

Uncaught ReferenceError: myData is not defined
at barChart (index2.js:19)
at index2.js:60
barChart @ index2.js:19
(anonymous) @ index2.js:60

Answer (score -2):

Got the issue

```
function barChart() {
    var that = {};

    that.render = function() {
        var myData = [10,20,30,40,50,60];
        var height = 500;
            var width = 500;
                    var colors = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, myData.length])
            .range(['#90ee90','#30c230'])
          var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
            .style('padding', '5 15px')
            .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
            .style('border-radius', '5px')
            .style('opacity', '0');

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(myData)])
            .range([0, height]);

        var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(d3.range(0, myData.length))
            .rangeRound([0, width]);
        d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
                .selectAll('rect')
                    .data(myData)
                    .enter().append('rect')
                        .style('fill', function(d, i){
                            return colors(i);
                        })
                        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
                        .attr('height', 0)
                        .attr('x', function(d, i){
                            return xScale(i);
                        })
                        .attr('y', height)
                .on('mouseover', function(d){
                    tooltip.transition()
                        .style('opacity', 1)

                    tooltip.html(d)
                        .style('left', (d3.event.pageX)+'px')
                        .style('top', (d3.event.pageY+'px'))
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5)

                })
                .on('mouseout', function(d){
                    tooltip.transition()
                        .style('opacity', 0)
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
                })
    };
        return that;
};

var c=barChart();
c.render();
```